# Best practices for data caching (storing) and REST API calls.

Tags: java, android, api, rest, caching

I never worked with REST APIs previously and I would like some information on the best practices for data caching (storing) and API call.

The API I want to use only allow 9000 request per day wich is fairly low for the kind of app I'll be doing.

The data output is JSON and I'll be working in Java / Android

Answer (score 1):

If you're not in control of the server side, then I would build the caching layer manually.  If you owned both sides, you could send an ETag header from the server to notify the client that changes have not been made, and then a REST library like Retrofit would handle the caching for you.  What I've done in the past when I did not have control over the server side but wanted to cache requests is have an in memory cache (optionally backed by persistent storage such as sqlite db) that contains a wrapper object that holds the url of the request, the raw byte array data of the response, the timestamp of when the cache entry was created, and optionally additional time/access information.  Then I'd create a simple class that maintains a map of these wrapper objects (keyed by the url) providing access with logic for invalidating the cache based on various timeout strategies.

If you want something lightweight just to make raw requests and you'll handle all the parsing and caching yourself, have a look at [http-request](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request).  If you want something that will get you up and running REALLY fast and handles just about everything for you, I'd recommend [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Comment: Bit of a late reply, but thanks a lot Rich, great advice.

I actually don't control both end points, I probably go for a sqlite DB with timestamp as you suggested.

I will take a look at Retrofit!